# PhpPowerpoint Manual Install

Tags: php, phppowerpoint

I'm trying to manually install PhpPowerpoint (not using composer)

I've WAMP installation having document_root  D:\wamp\www\

i've copied the PhpPowerpoint folder under the following path D:\wamp\www\php\PhpOffice\

using the manual installation code (the code is in a file D:\wamp\www\php\agile\expMSPowerpoint.php):

```
require_once '../PhpOffice/PhpPowerpoint/Autoloader.php';
PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Autoloader::register();
$objPHPPowerPoint = new PhpPowerpoint(); <<<< Error in this line
```

i get the error:

Fatal error: Class 'PhpPowerpoint' not found in D:\wamp\www\php\agile\expMSPowerpoint.php on line 435

Any help to get it installed would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the PHP `realpath` http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

From the manual page:

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to
>   '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and returns
>   the canonicalized absolute pathname.

Comment: Also you may want to check that the code and directory of PhpPowerpoint is executable and available to your web server user.  Otherwise, experiment with full path to it and see if it works --just as a test.